# Relationship between factory design pattern and polymorphism

Tags: c#, c++, polymorphism, factory

Is factory design pattern can only be used when there is a polymorphic behavior exists?

Comment: We usually just call non-polymorphic factories "constructors".

Comment: Obviously not. You can use a factory whenever you want. There is nothing that _forces_ you to use or not use a design pattern.

Comment: afaik the go4 pattern is specifically about creating objects of different type. Sometimes I need to pass around a function that creates objects (of one type) because I cannot pass around a constructor, I call the function object a "factory" and I don't think this will create lots of confusion among ppl familiar with the factory pattern

Answer (score 2):

One use of the factory pattern occurs because there is no such thing as a virtual constructor. If you want to create an object where its specific class depends on runtime polymorphic behavior, you can let the factory's `create` member function be a virtual function.

However, this is not the only use case for a factory class. Off the top of my head another use for factory would be to enforce two-stage initialization. If all the objects your factory creates require an `initialize` member function to be called on them and you can't do it in the constructor for whatever reason (say, for example, you want to use `shared_from_this`; it won't be valid in the constructor). The create member function in the factory can call `initialize` before returning the object.

Answer (score 0):

You use the factory pattern if you want to be able to change the concrete type that is created later on - in other words to use polymorphism to return an instance of a derived class in the form of the base class.

So polymorphism is a precondition for the factory pattern to work. Without polymorphism, you couldn't return an instance of a derived class in the form of the base class.

Comment: Not necessarily if you have continuation-passing style.